# Not understanding derivative of a matrix-matrix product.

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I am trying to figure out a the derivative of a matrix-matrix multiplication, but to no avail. [This document](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) seems to show me the answer, but I am having a hard time parsing it and understanding it.

Here is my problem: We have $\mathbf{D} \in \Re^{m n}$, $\mathbf{W} \in \Re^{m q}$, and $\mathbf{X} \in \Re^{q n}$. Furthermore, $\mathbf{D} = \mathbf{W}\mathbf{X}$. (NOT an element wise multiplication - a normal matrix-matrix multiply).

I am trying to derive the derivative of $\mathbf{D}$, w.r.t $\mathbf{W}$, and the derivative of $\mathbf{D}$, w.r.t $\mathbf{X}$.

My class note this is taken from seems to indicate that
$$
\frac{\delta \mathbf{D}}{\delta \mathbf{W}} = \mathbf{X}^{T} \text{ and that } \frac{\delta \mathbf{D}}{\delta \mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{W}^{T}, 
$$
but I am floored as to how he derived this. Furthermore, in taking the derivatives, we are asking ourselves how every element in $\mathbf{D}$ changes with perturbations by every element in, say, $\mathbf{X}$, - so wouldn't the resulting combinations blow up to be a-lot more than what $\mathbf{W}^{T}$ has? I cant even see how the dimensionality is right here.

**EDIT:** Id like to add the context of this question. It's coming from [here](http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/), and here is my marked screen-shot of my problem. How are they deriving those terms? (Note: I understand the chain-rule aspect, and I am not wondering about that. I am asking about the simpler intermediate step).

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

For the first question alone (without context) I'm going to prove something else first (then check the $\boxed{\textbf{EDIT}}$ for what is asked):

Suppose we have three matrices $A,X,B$ that are $n\times p$, $p\times r$, and $r\times m$ respectively. Any element $w_{ij}$ of their product $W=AXB$ is expressed by:

$$w_{ij}=\sum_{h=1}^r\sum_{t=1}^pa_{it}x_{th}b_{hj}$$
Then we can show that: $$s=\frac {\partial w_{ij}}{\partial x_{dc}}=a_{id}b_{cj}$$
(because all terms, expect the one multiplied by $x_{dc}$, vanish)

One might deduce (in an *almost* straightforward way) that the matrix  $S$ is the Kronecker product of $B^T$ and $A$ so that:$$\frac {\partial AXB}{\partial X}=B^T⊗A$$

Replacing either $A$ or $B$ with the appropriate identity matrix, gives you the derivative you want.

$$\boxed{\textbf{EDIT}}$$

Upon reading the article you added (and after some sleep!), I've noticed that $dD$ is not $\partial D$ in their notation, but rather $\dfrac {\partial f}{\partial D}$ where $f$ is a certain function of $W$ and $X$ while $D=WX$. This means that the first expression you're having problems with is $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial D}X^T$$
Since the author at the beginning stated that he'd use the incorrect expression "gradient on" something to mean "partial derivative" with respect to that same thing.
 So any element of $\partial f/\partial W$ can be written as $\partial f/\partial W_{ij}$. And any element of $D$:
$$D_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^qW_{ik}X_{kj}$$

We can write $$df=\sum_i\sum_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial D_{ij}}dD_{ij}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial W_{dc}}=\sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial D_{ij}}\frac{\partial D_{ij}}{\partial W_{dc}}=\sum_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial D_{dj}}\frac{\partial D_{dj}}{\partial W_{dc}}$$
This last equality is true since all terms with $i\neq d$ drop off.
Due to the product $D=WX$, we have $$\frac{\partial D_{dj}}{\partial W_{dc}}=X_{cj}$$ and so $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial W_{dc}}=\sum_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial D_{dj}}X_{cj}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial W_{dc}}=\sum_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial D_{dj}}X_{jc}^T$$

This means that the matrix $\partial f/\partial W$ is the product of $\partial f/\partial D$ and $X^T$. I believe this is what you're trying to grasp, and what's asked of you in the last paragraph of the screenshot. Also, as the next paragraph *after* the screenshot hints, you could've started out with small matrices to work this out before noticing the pattern, and generalizing as I attempted to do directly in the above proof. The same reasoning proves the second expression as well...

Comment: Hi GeorgSaliba, I edited my question to give you the exact context of my question. Thanks...

Comment: @Spacey It's rather late where I am, and I'm too lazy to read all the page now, but are the matrices by any chance orthogonal?

Comment: @Spacey  Because what they wrote is $dW=(dD)X^T$ whereas what you expressed is $dD=(dW)X^T$ or something of the sort.

Comment: $dW=(dD)X^T$  makes sense using the product rule and the fact that $X^TX=I$ if $X$ is indeed orthogonal

Comment: Hi @GeorgSaliba no they are not orthogonal - he means it for any general matrix... Also I understand the chain rule aspect, but not clear on simply what $\frac{\delta D}{\delta X}$ and $\frac{\delta D}{\delta W}$should be equal to? Thanks!

Comment: @Spacey I'll read the page and get back to you as we're not agreeing on certain terms.

Comment: Thank you GeorgSaliba - but I am still not getting it... The thing I am stuck on is: why is $\frac{\delta D_{dj}}{\delta W_{dc}} = X_{cj}$? ... This is what I am stuck on... thanks.

Comment: @Spacey in order for an element from $D$ to contain the variable $W_{dc}$ is for it to have the same row index $d$ otherwise, deriving will lead to a zero. Then, if you look at the product of the two matrices, you notice that there are many terms $W$ with row index $d$ but only one has column index $c$, so all terms vanish except $W_{dc}X_{cj}$ which when derived with respect to $W_{dc}$ gives $ X_{cj}$.

Comment: What is "the matrix  $S$"?

Comment: @GeorgSaliba, thanks for the great answer. Here "This means that the matrix ∂/∂ is the product of ∂/∂ and .", is this "product" matrix multiplication or element-wise product? Thanks!

Comment: @TongZhou It's a matrix product.

Answer (score 21):

Like most articles on Machine Learning / Neural Networks, the linked document is an awful mixture of code snippets and poor mathematical notation.

If you read the comments preceding the code snippet, you'll discover that **dX** does not refer to an increment or differential of $X,$ or to
the matrix-by-matrix derivative  $\frac{\partial W}{\partial X}.\;$
Instead it is supposed to represent $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X}$, i.e. the gradient of an *unspecified* objective function $\Big({\rm i.e.}\;\phi(D)\Big)$ with respect to one of the factors of the matrix argument: $\;D=WX$.

Likewise, **dD** does not refer to an increment (or differential) of **D** but to the gradient $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial D}$

Here is a short derivation of the mathematical content of the code snippet.
$$\eqalign{
D &= WX \\
dD &= dW\,X + W\,dX
 \quad&\big({\rm differential\,of\,}D\big) \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial D} &= G
 \quad&\big({\rm gradient\,wrt\,}D\big) \\
d\phi &= G:dD
 \quad&\big({\rm differential\,of\,}\phi\big) \\
 &= G:dW\,X \;+ G:W\,dX \\
 &= GX^T\!:dW + W^TG:dX \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial W} &= GX^T
 \quad&\big({\rm gradient\,wrt\,}W\big) \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= W^TG
 \quad&\big({\rm gradient\,wrt\,}X\big) \\
}$$
Unfortunately, the author decided to use the following variable names in the code:

- **dD**   for $\;\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial D}$

  **dX**   for $\;\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X}$

  **dW**   for $\;\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial W}$

With this in mind, it is possible to make sense of the code snippet
$$\eqalign{
{\bf dW} &= {\bf dD}\cdot{\bf X}^T \\
{\bf dX} &= {\bf W}^T\cdot{\bf dD} \\
}$$
but the notation is *extremely* confusing for anyone who is mathematically inclined.

(NB: This answer simply reiterates points made in GeorgSaliba's excellent post)

Comment: What does the ":" stand for?

Comment: @NicholasLP Frobenius inner product.

Comment: "awful mixture of code snippets and poor mathematical notation" is such a true statement

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to GeorgSaliba's excellent answer, you can see this must be the case intuitively.

Given a function $f(D)$ with $D=WX$, **if all variables were scalars**, we clearly have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial D}\frac{\partial D}{\partial W}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial D}X$$
Now in the non-scalar case we expect the same exact form, up to some change of multiplication order, transpose, etc., due the non-scalar nature, but the overall form has to reduce to the same form in the scalar case, so it can't really be substantially different from the above.

Now, ${\partial f}/{\partial \bf D}$ in the non-scalar case has the same dimensions of $\bf D$, say a $n \times p$ matrix, but $\bf X$ is an $m × p$ matrix, which means we can't really do the multiplication as it stands. What we can do, is transpose $\bf X$, allowing us to do the multiplication, and giving the correct result of $n \times m$ for ${\partial f}/{\partial \bf W}$ which of course must have the same dimensions as $\bf W$. Thus, we see that we must have:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bf W}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bf D}{\bf X}^T$$
One can formalize this into an actual proof, but we'll let this stand as only an intuitive guide for now.

Comment: from $
\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial D} \frac{\partial D}{\partial W}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial D} X^T$, can we conclude that $\frac{\partial D}{\partial W}=X^T$  (recall $D=WX$)? I think it's not correct as it should be $I \otimes W$ , but don't know why it's wrong.

Comment: Sorry, a typo in my comment above, it should be $I \otimes X$

Answer (score 3):

You note is not correct, you missed the trace function, i.e. $\frac{\partial tr(XA) }{\partial X} = A^T$, check the 'Derivative of traces' section of the Matrix Cookbook.

Having said that, the confusion here is that you are trying to take the derivative w.r.t. a matrix of a MATRIX-VALUED function, the result should be a four-way tensor (array). If you check the Matrix Cookbook, it always talks about SCALAR-VALUED function. So I guess you missed some function here around D, maybe det() or trace(). Otherwise, you have to take derivative of each element of D, which will give you a matrix for each element.

Answer (score 1):

I think your note is not correct.

$$f_{ij}=w_{ik}x_{kj}$$

$$\frac{\partial {f_{ij}}}{\partial {w_{mn}}}=tr(M)$$ where M is a block matrix and its diagonal is $X^T$ and its other element matrix is null matrix.

Comment: I should add, this is a normal matrix multiplication, not an element-wise one...

Comment: Ive also edited my question with the context for you, and the image of the exact lines I do not get.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just the code from cs231n + print statements to see
"small, explicit examples", here 0 / 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866757/not-understanding-derivative-of-a-matrix-matrix-producto
# http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/#mat  Gradients for vectorized operations
# Work with small, explicit examples  here 0 / 1

from __future__ import division, print_function
import numpy as np

def pname( name ):
    """ pname( "name" / "expr" ): eval -> num / vec / array, print """
    A = eval(name)
    print( "\n%s %s: \n%s" % (
            name, getattr( A, "shape", "" ), A ))

np.random.seed( 3 )  # reproducible randint
W = np.random.randint( 0, 2, size=(5, 10) )  # [0, 2): 0 / 1
X = np.random.randint( 0, 2, size=(10, 3) )

Y = W.dot(X)  # D in the original
# now suppose we had the gradient on Y  -- here means ∂f/∂Y, for some f( Y )
dY = np.random.randint( 0, 2, size=Y.shape )
dW = dY.dot(X.T)
dX = W.T.dot(dY)

print( """
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Y = W.dot(X)
dY = ∂f/∂Y, for some f( Y )
dW = ∂f/∂W = ∂f/∂Y ∂Y/∂W = ∂f/∂Y . Xᵀ
dX = ∂f/∂X = ∂f/∂Y ∂Y/∂X = Wᵀ . ∂f/∂Y
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
""" )

for name in "W X Y dY dW dX ".split():
    pname( name )
```